# jobTracker property in job.properties of oozie

Tags: oozie, hadoop2

I'm using hadoop-2.7.2 and oozie-4.0.1, what should be the jobTracker value in job.properties file of oozie workflow. I referred this link;

http://hadooptutorial.info/apache-oozie-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04/

which states that, in YARN architecture the job tracker runs on 8032 port and i'm currently using this. But in mapred-site.xml of hadoop i'm having the value hdfs://localhost:54311 for job tracker property.

I'm confused, can any one explain me or provide some useful links for installing oozie and running jobs on oozie.

Currently, i'm not able to run workflow jobs on oozie, it is in a Running state for a long time and then it is getting suspended with a connection error. Job DAG is also not getting generated, it is throwing some UI Exception.

Please anyone help me with this.

Comment: Check the value of the `yarn.resourcemanager.address` in the yarn and use that. It will be just `host:port`.

Comment: Hi thanks, but where can we find this property(yarn.resourcemanager.address). I'm not having this property in yarn-site.xml

Comment: go to conf directory and do a grep. `grep -ri "yarn.resourcemanager.address" *`

Comment: I am able to find this into `hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml` file.

Comment: I have not given this property inside yarn-site.xml. is the default value is 8032 for yarn.resourcemanager.address.

Comment: And also my jobs are in Running state for a long time and getting Suspended with this exception: JA006: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114119/discussion-between-younghobbit-and-karthi).

Answer (score 2):

In your properties file just pass the Resorucemanager address which you have configured in the yarn-site.xml or directly parse the resourcemanager address in workflow.xml file as

```
        <job-tracker>localhost:8032</job-tracker>
```

While running properties file you need to specify in which host the oozie server will be running, I think in that part you didn't face any issues right. Then paste the error message and update the question.

**EDITED:**
Configurations needed to be in yarn-site.xml

```
    <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
       <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <description>NM Webapp address.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>${yarn.nodemanager.hostname}:8042</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <description>hostname </description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
  </property>
```

you can either specify hostname or localhost for Pesudo node cluster. 
for HA cluster  need the below

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html

Comment: Hi, i'm getting this error; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680428/running-sqoop-action-on-oozie

Comment: I have not configured ResourceManagerAddress in yarn-site.xml. can you please tell what are the properties that has to be configured in yarn-site.xml.

Comment: These are the services that are running after i started hadoop and oozie;                                                                                               DataNode
Bootstrap
NameNode
NodeManager
Jps
ResourceManager
SecondaryNameNode                                                                                       Apart from these does any other services needs to be started.

Comment: Just look at the EDITs for configurations, I think you using pesudonode cluster or multinode cluster . ??

Comment: i'm getting this error: JA017: Unknown hadoop job [job_local2078275128_0001] associated with action [0000000-160609190816087-oozie-hado-W@mr-node].  Failing this action!

Comment: can you please update the application master log that job ?

Answer (score 1):

in Production Environment , probably you have configured a **High-Availbility** yarn cluster. In this case , the oozie job tracker config in job.properties should be the configuration value of `yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id`.

a cut of my yarn configuration :

```
 <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.enabled</name>
                <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id</name>
                <value>datayarn</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.rm-ids</name>
                <value>resourcemanager1,resourcemanager2</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.resourcemanager1</name>
                <value>11.11.11.11</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.resourcemanager2</name>
                <value>11.11.11.12</value>
        </property>
```

So , the jobTracker value should be:**`datayarn`**